# In headless chrome, how do i change the default output filename?

Tags: google-chrome-headless, webpage-screenshot

I am using this command to generate the screenshot
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=1280,1696

It's generating the output in current directory with name screenshot.jpeg. I want to change the default output directory as well as output filename. Can somebody tell me the correct options I need to use?

Comment: looks like it would be cool to accept the answer provided

Answer (score 6):

you can specify your filename in `--screenshot` option.

eg.,

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=newfilename.png https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Comment: this also holds for saving as pdf, i.e. use `--print-to-pdf=` for that